# Poor video performance with a Dell D800

Tags: nvidia, dell

I upgraded my Dell D800 from 8x to 10x with very poor results to my video. Everything on the display seemed do be poorly rendered. I upgraded to 11.10 and some of the items are rendered properly but not all. The mouse pointer for example is simply a smudge of pixels.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you (or anyone else) haven't resolved this:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1602577

Posts #6 & 7 seem to give a solution. Hope this helps...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.